# Creating an Interface for an Entity Framework Core DbContext so that it can be injected/tested?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I have a fairly basic Entity Framework Core DbContext that I use for my app.  I am injecting this context but I would like to further decouple the context so that I can do testing and/or replace it with a different context/db down the road.

What is the best practice way of creating an appropriate interface for the DbContext?

My DbContext:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    private string _connectionString;
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options){}
    public MyContext(string connectionString) => _connectionString = connectionString;

    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Person> Persons{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Detail> Details{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    ...(about 35 additional tables)
}
```

In my interface do I need to create a member for each of the DbSet public members? Is there a way to make the interface simpler?

And then do I need to create an interface for each member? And then interfaces for sub-members of those members, etc.... (how far down the rabbit hole would I need to go?)

Comment: I would say quite close to the entrance of the hole :) So simply provide a different connection string, or different provider for the database when testin. InMemory provider is quite good for testing, of course depends on how much of the provider-specific things you want covered...

Comment: I understand your suggestions for testing.  I guess the issue I am really trying to solve is the DI/decoupling aspect.  When I go down that path I keep slipping on the edge of that hole. ;)

Answer (score 1):

EF was designed with the idea that you'll swap out the provider for testing, not replace a DbContext with something else.  If you do want to program to a repository abstraction over a DbContext, something like this isn't too bad:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    void Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    void Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    void Remove<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    IQueryable<TEntity> Query<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    TEntity GetById<TEntity, TId>(TId id) where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Implemented in your DbContext something like:

```
void IRepository.Add<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    Add(entity);
}

void IRepository.Update<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    Update(entity);
}

void IRepository.Remove<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    Remove(entity);
}

IQueryable<TEntity> IRepository.Query<TEntity>()
{
    return Set<TEntity>();
}

TEntity IRepository.GetById<TEntity, TId>(TId id)
{
    var entity = Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
    if (entity == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"No Entity {typeof(TEntity).Name} found for id {id}");

    return entity;
}

int IRepository.SaveChanges()
{
    return this.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify a DBSet for each desired table in your DB. The only tables that need DBSets are ones that you plan to access directly. In EF Core, your entities should have relationships set up between the objects so that you can perform more complex querying. For example, you probably never need to access an Order's Details desperately, you should be able to retrieve the order with its details to retrieve/change what you need( via a command like context.Orders.Include(x => x.Details).FindAsync(id)).

If you are looking to test a DbContext, I'd recommend using the Moq.EntityFrameworkCore library, https://github.com/MichalJankowskii/Moq.EntityFrameworkCore. It is the closest ability to duplicate how DbContext Works. It is also possible to spin up an in-memory db for testing which you can read about here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli.

I would not recommend trying to abstract back from the DbContex to an interface without first assessing available options that support DBContext when testing.